# Is it possible to override the spring security authentication error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

We are using spring boot 2.2.2.

I want to return the custom error message in the json response along with 401 status code when user enters the wrong credentials for that I did following steps.

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public WebSecurityConfig(RepositoryUserDetailsService userDetailsService RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.restAuthenticationEntryPoint = restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/proj-name/**/*.{js,html}")
                .antMatchers("/test/**");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

 @Bean
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider customDaoAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationProvider customDaoAuthenticationProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        customDaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new PasswordEncoderConfig().encoder());
        customDaoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return customDaoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customDaoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + "");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationProvider.java

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
                                                  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "test bad credentials"));
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(
                    messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials","Invalid credentials"));
        }
        
        }
        }
```

When I hit the `/login` api is returning the following response: `Full authentication is required to access this resource`

If I add `.antMatchers("/error").permitAll()` is returning the following response.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1594970514264,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

I tried adding @Component annotation on the CustomAuthenticationProvider then it throws the following error on server startup: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set`

I tried adding the CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler by following the [url](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler), but didn't work. I've seen couple of articles, but that examples also didn't work. I've also tried creating an exception handler class with @ControllerAdvice annotation still didn't work. Is there any other way to override the default error message or am I missing any annotations or configuration? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: try changing `antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()` to `antMatchers("/login").permitAll()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it still returns the `"message": "Unauthorized",`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a controller advice to handle the error thrown by your service :

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AppointmentErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleError(HttpServletRequest request, BadCredentialsException ex) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(...); //retrieve info from BadCredentialsException
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, apiError);
}
```